# None type object has no attribute - how to run Python Beautiful Soup to pass the none types

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am new to Python so any help would be appreciated. I have a web crawler using beautifulsoup. It works but for the below and returns the error 'None type object has no attribute'. I know it means it has come across a page where there is no entry. How do I stop this error and make it return all the other pages that have entries. Some of the pages in the web crawler have the entry and some are blank.

I write them both to a csv aswell: 
What to do so it passes the none types and doesnt stop with the error?
Thanks

```
bbb = re.compile('First listed')
next_a = soup.find(text=bbb).parent.parent.get_text(strip=True)           

ccc = re.compile('First listed')
next_b = soup.find(text=ccc).parent.parent.parent.get_text(strip=True)

writer.writerow([next_a, next_b])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the exception and ignore the specific NoneType error:

```
try:
    yourinstance.hello()
except AttributeError as ae:
    if "NoneType" in ae:
        # ignore it
        pass
    else:
        print "error occur:" + str(ae)
```

Alternatively, you invoke method() when the instance is not none

```
if yourInstance:
    yourInstance.method()
```

or

```
if yourInstance is not None:
    yourInstance.method()
```

Comment: @hello11 replace it with the instance you got NoneType error

Comment: It come up with a invalid syntax if I put:      if yourInstance is not None: 
      yourInstance.method(bbb = re.compile('First listed'))
     next_a = soup.find(text=bbb).parent.parent.get_text(strip=True)